# Why is this static route not taking effect?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, routing, networkmanager

## Original Question

I am running Ubuntu and network manager. I have two different interfaces, `eth0` and `eth1`. Network manager has (as far as I can tell) correctly added this manual route:

```
~$ ip route

default via 172.16.0.2 dev eth1  proto static 
10.0.0.0/8 via 172.16.0.2 dev eth1  proto static 
130.35.0.0/16 via 172.16.0.2 dev eth1  proto static 
...
172.16.0.0/12 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.0.15  metric 1 
192.135.82.0/24 via 172.16.0.2 dev eth1  proto static
```

`eth0` appears down, but that seems to me to be a separate problem. Even given the above routes, the IP stack seems to be preferring `eth0`:

```
~$ ping 130.35.249.52
PING 130.35.249.52 (130.35.249.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 130.35.249.52 ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 17132ms

~$ ping -Ieth1 130.35.249.52
PING 130.35.249.52 (130.35.249.52) from 172.16.0.15 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 130.35.249.52: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=210 ms
```

Additionally,

```
~$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 

~$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.0.2      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
10.0.0.0        172.16.0.2      255.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 eth1
130.35.0.0      172.16.0.2      255.255.0.0     UG        0 0          0 eth1
...
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.240.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
192.135.82.0    172.16.0.2      255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 eth1

~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:01:b1:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe01:b1f6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:35:eb:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.15/12 brd 172.31.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe35:eb24/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can I force the IP stack to obey those routes?

## Routing Successful

```
~$ ip route get 130.35.249.52
130.35.249.52 via 172.16.0.2 dev eth1  src 172.16.0.15
    cache
```

This situation is getting a little bit more screwy. It seems that the failure in the first ping is *temporary*, the second ping to `eth1` succeeds, and then subsequent pings to `eth0` route correctly. It's difficult for me to determine how the IP stack gets into this state, but for now I'm going to try to solve a different DNS-related problem.

Comment: Among the left out lines there is none with `eth0`? What is the output of `ip rule`?

Comment: `eth0` is not mentioned. See above for `ip rule`.

Comment: Please update your port to include netstat -nr output.

Comment: Please also add the output of `ip addr`.

Comment: Ok, those are added as well.

Comment: I have no good ideas any more. Everything else results from desperation: (a) `iptables -L OUTPUT -nv; iptables -t nat -L OUTPUT -nv; iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING -nv`  (b) `strace ping 130.35.249.52`  (c) while trying to ping: `tcpdump -i eth0 -n icmp` and `tcpdump -i eth1 -n icmp`

Comment: Please post the whole output of `ip route`, as well as the output of `ip route get 130.35.249.52`

Comment: _eth0 appears down, but that seems to me to be a separate problem._ From the `ip addr` output, eth0 is UP.  It may have no IP address, but Linux using a so-called "Weak End System Model", the kernel will accept to use IP 172.16.0.15 on `eth0`

Comment: Also, forget about the deprecated `netstat -nr` command. It adds no information compared to `ip route` and rely on backward compability in the kernel which often has to lie.

Comment: @BatchyX The Weak End System Model **allows** sending packets with `eth1` source address via eth0 but doesn't explain why this happens.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Reinderlen may have hidden a route in [...] going via eth0.

Comment: @BatchyX May. But see the first two comments.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Once the output of `ip route get 130.35.249.52` is known, we will be settled.  In fact, there is no proof that `eth0` is actually used on his first `ping` test.

Comment: See edited question. I'm giving up on this problem for now and am going to attempt to solve http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123058/how-do-i-determine-where-dns-requests-fail-in-the-tcp-stack .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that UDP packets were not being passed. I don't know why. TCP DNS works just fine. In the end I used `network-manager-openconnect` and only retained one virtual adapter in VirtualBox, and it works.